# BETWEEN and DATE_ADD is not working in my case

Tags: mysql

I have sales in my database going back 9 days and this query is not returning anything why?

```
SELECT * FROM `sales`
WHERE date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND 
(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -10 DAY))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to switch the parameter. From must be lower than to.

```
SELECT * FROM `sales`
WHERE date BETWEEN 
(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -10 DAY)) AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Your current query would return records *greater* than now or *earlier* than 10 days ago, thus excluding the very range you intended to target.

For more Informations see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal
>   to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. This is equivalent
>   to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments
>   are of the same type. Otherwise type conversion takes place according
>   to the rules described in Section 12.2, “Type Conversion in Expression
>   Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

Comment: thanks for your help I'm tired and I missed it feel stupid ;-)